# Idea behind boundary states in BCFT

Tags: hilbert-space, string-theory, conformal-field-theory, boundary-conditions

In Blumenhagen's book on CFT, in the BCFT chapter he introduces the concept of a boundary state. TO do this, he first explains how there is a duality between the one-loop open string worldsheet and the tree-level closed string worldsheet. He immediately goes on to saying that:

[image]
[image]

I do not see how one can conclude that the boundary "can be described by a coherent state" in the closed sector.

Furthermore, he goes on to saying that the boundary states must satisfy the gluing conditions. This seems completely arbitrary to me. How do we know this must be the case?